# Thymeleaf with iframe

Tags: javascript, java, spring, thymeleaf

I am having an issue using a javascript switch statement with Thymeleaf. I have searched throughout but cannot find any examples so I am might just be off on design or understanding. I am trying to use iframes to keep a main banner at the top of this SPA. This is not a public web site but a rather simple application. (Java/Spring/Thymeleaf).

Anyhow given:

```
switch (event.target.id)
                {
                    case "dashtab":
                        $('.iframeContainer').height(1100);
                        $('#iframe').attr('src', 'Dashtab.html');
                        break;
                    case "detailtab":
                        $('.iframeContainer').height(800);
                        $('#iframe').attr('src', 'Details.html');
                        break;
```

I am trying to call the individual html pages. To do this normally (not in a switch stmt) I would simply call:

```
<iframe id="iframe" th:replace="Orders::html"></iframe>
```

Any thoughts as to the syntax for this? None of my attempts at using the attr/src is working. I could not find examples or documentation on the usual websites.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly is your problem. The HTML template fragment is exactly what you use to render the iframe? The JS snippet provided is what you use to switch the source of the iframe inside the same page?

Comment: I am also a bit unclear on the problem you need to solve here (I did see your comment in the answer, as well)... Any clarifications you can add to the question would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don, you have to specify a working URL for the iframe source attribute (src). For example, the link like http://127.0.0.1:8080/Dashtab.html if your HTML pages are served and accessible through this path.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The above works perfectly and is actual example code. The Dashtab.html (using spring) resolves to an actual internal URL. (Spring MVC). My question is around how to get thymeleaf to make the call per the working example of <iframe id="iframe" th:replace="Orders::html"></iframe> which is NOT in a case stmt.